# Proof that computer communication only exists of function calls and events

Tags: architecture, terminology, language-agnostic, computer-science, theory

I am writing a paper about the use of a message broker for inter-process communication where I state that all computer communications can be broken down into two categories:

- Function calls
- Events

My reasoning for this that code either needs to run other code to run to achieve its goal (function call) or merely triggers other code that it does not depend on (event).

I am fairly confident in this claim, though I was not able to find a source that either supports or denies this statement.

---

What are your thoughts about this and can anybody cite a source that either supports or denies my statement?

Thank you

Comment: seems like a tautology. Either you get a return message or not. but what if you got multiple answers?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by that. Is this a response to how I phrased my question or to my statement about computer communications?

Comment: what is your distinction between a function and an event? both 'run other code' why is one dependent on the code and one not?

Comment: My reasoning is that a function call is used when the originating code needs specific other code to run. In the case of an event, the originating does not "care" about what happens with the event.

So "dependant" here means that the code wants to achieve a certain result and it "depends" on something that other code does to achieve the desired result

Comment: if you have a function which returns null, in what way does teh callign code 'depend' on the result? or is that an event

Comment: When a function gets called, it will (almost) always do _something_. When a function returns `null` or `void`, it might have changed a variable or done some other action. But it was called by the originating code for a very specific reason. **EDIT**: perhaps my reasoning is starting to become too specific. Very simplified: an event is a message that is thrown into the air by code that does not care about what other code picks it up and a function call is a message where some code wants a very specific piece of other code to be called.

Comment: I think of function calls as invocation on the same thread of control.  I don't think of function calls as a form of inter-thread or inter-process communication.  You can hide inter-process communication within a function call but that doesn't make the underlying communication mechanism function invocation.  Perhaps what you're getting after is [request-reply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) messaging vs. one-way messaging?  Also relevant: [Query & Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Comment: seems like an odd distinction, If i assign an event handler in classA to an even raised by classB the program as a whole depends on the event handler being called as much as if I do it the other way around

Comment: Compare also [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), which supports bi-directional communication vs. [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) for one-way messaging.  Note that TCP is built on top of UDP.

Comment: Perhaps I need to re-evaluate my statement. I was trying to abstract it to a level beyond programming languages, services or processes. In my opinion request-reply is a sort of function call because are basically calling code on another program. But as @doc-brown noted, I first need to define a rigid definition of these terms

Comment: Pehaps the distinction you want is synchronous vs asynchronous. I think the phrases 'function call' and 'event' are too specific, since readers may think of very particular things (e.g. pushing stack frames, etc.). Maybe something more general, like "one piece of code can run another either synchronously (waiting for a result) or asynchronously (not waiting for a result)".

Comment: I agree that I need to change my terminology, though "synchronous" and "asynchronous" indicate the technical workings. I was looking for trying to discriminate them by result. An "event", in this context, can trigger one or more other actions, but it can also be ignored if there are no listeners. A "function call" triggers a single function and always* gives a single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to proof such a statement about "all computer communication", you first need

- a mathematical model about a computer system and the communication within the system
- and a rigid definition what "function call" and "event" mean within this model

So start with that. Otherwise this whole discussion becomes purely philosophical and all statements will stay purely opinionated.

Comment: I was hoping that there were already (peer reviewed) papers about this topic. I now see that if I want to base my paper on this, I would at least need to do these things.

Comment: @Vinno97: I don't know if there are any scientific papers about this topic, but this site is surely not the right place to find them, since asking for 3rd party resource is off-topic here.

Comment: I did not know that. My apologies